# Возможно ли нарисовать точку вне формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Возможно ли нарисовать точку на экране монитора (в любой или конкретной его части), не на форме!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это, конечно же, возможно. Любое устройство графического вывода имеет свой контекст, описатель контекста устройства, при чем в роли устройства может выступать любое окно Windows. Так как рабочий стол - это такое же обыкновенное окно Windows( которое всегда крейтится первым, поэтому имеет идентификатор контекста устройства = 0 ), то с ним можно производить любые операции, которые только можно производить с окнами. Например, можно рисовать в этом окне( точнее в его контексте ). Вам остается всего лишь создать новый объект класса Bitmap, присвоить его идентификатору контекста контекст рабочего стола и точно так же рисовать в этом самом BitMap`e, при этом все, как вы уже, надеюсь, поняли, будет выводиться на окно рабочего стола. В Delphi, например, присваивание идентификатора контекста рабочего стола выглядит так:

```
bitmap.canvas.handle := GetDC(0);
```

---

Да, чуть не забыл, что GetDC() - WinApi функция для получения контекста устройства ( HDC ) вывода окна по его хэндлу(HWND), поэтому не забудьте импортировать данную функцию из библиотеки. Вроде так:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "GetDC")]
public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Comment: Это будет точка на десктопе, а не "на мониторе" :)  Если при этом на место рисования будет загорожено окном, то точку видно не будет.

Боюсь, нарисовать точку именно "на мониторе" невозможно. Для рисования в Windows в любом случае необходим Device Context, которыми владеют окна.

Comment: Ну можно поставить какую-либо прозрачную форму на весь экран и на ней нарисовать, это не существенно.